Variables Nativas en CSS. Declaración
Mas bien es una consulta sobre la declaración de variables en CSS. Es conocido la importancia de definirlas en el pseudo elemento :root, por los niveles de especificidad. Pero dentro del :root, ¿Es necesario anteponer al nombre de las variables -- (doble guion medio)? ó ¿Puedo definirlas sin ellos?, ¿Es un consenso, es obligatorio, es una exigencia del compilador, puede cambiarse?
Gracias por aceptar mi pregunta.

Para crear una custom property hay que hacer uso de los dos guiones -- como prefijo al nombre que vamos a utilizar. En este caso, hemos creado una variable CSS llamada --background-color, al que le hemos asignado el valor black.
:root {
  --background-color: black;
}

Mira que en este caso, hemos establecido la variable dentro del selector con pseudoclase :root. Esta pseudoclase hace referencia al elemento raíz del documento, es decir, al elemento . La diferencia entre utilizar html o :root como selector es que este último tiene algo más de especificidad CSS. Mientras el selector html tiene (0,0,1), :root tendría (0,1,0).
A la hora de utilizar una custom property, hay que utilizar la función var(), indicando el nombre de la variable así
:root {
  --background-color: black;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
}

Puedes leer y aprender más en: https://lenguajecss.com/css/variables-css/css-custom-properties/ y también en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties y https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp
